# Create JSON with PHP (multilevel)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have issue with creating right JSON.

Here is what I receive from MySQL:

```
ID      room    startDate   stopDate

4       100     2015-02-03  2015-02-11
103     101     2015-02-03  2015-02-04
104     101     2015-02-22  2015-03-08
203     102     2015-01-27  2015-01-29
204     102     2015-02-05  2015-02-10
```

And my function to fetch result:

```php
public static function read() {
    $SQL = "****";

    $res = Calendar::con()->query($SQL);
    $calendar = array();
    $period = array();

    $previous = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $calendarr = new Calendar();
        $order = new Period();

        $current = $row['room'];

        $calendarr->room = $row['room'];
        $order->checkIn = $row['startDate'];
        $order->checkOut = $row['stopDate'];
        array_push($period, $order);
        $calendarr->period = $period;

        if ($current == $previous) {
            $period = array();
            $calendarr->debug = 'equal';
            array_push($calendar, $calendarr);
        } else {
            array_push($calendar, $calendarr);
            $calendarr->debug = 'not equal';
        }
        $previous = $current;
    }
    return $calendar;
}
```

Finally I build JSON (This part of code is OK):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "room": "100",
      "period": [
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-02-03",
          "checkOut": "2015-02-11"
        }
      ],
      "debug": "not equal"
    },
    {
      "room": "101",
      "period": [
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-02-03",
          "checkOut": "2015-02-11"
        },
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-02-03",
          "checkOut": "2015-02-04"
        }
      ],
      "debug": "not equal"
    },
    {
      "room": "101",
      "period": [
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-02-03",
          "checkOut": "2015-02-11"
        },
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-02-03",
          "checkOut": "2015-02-04"
        },
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-02-22",
          "checkOut": "2015-03-08"
        }
      ],
      "debug": "equal"
    },
    {
      "room": "102",
      "period": [
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-01-27",
          "checkOut": "2015-01-29"
        }
      ],
      "debug": "not equal"
    },
    {
      "room": "102",
      "period": [
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-01-27",
          "checkOut": "2015-01-29"
        },
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-02-05",
          "checkOut": "2015-02-10"
        }
      ],
      "debug": "equal"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "success": true,
    "msg": ""
  }
}
```

But my JSON is wrong. Because I need grouping by "room". When room for current row and room for next row is equal checkIn and checkOut date must be added to a one room. Records for one room can be more then 2. I need to correct php read function.

**UPDATE:**

After right answer I receive right JSON:

My SQL is:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE (room = 100 OR room = 101 OR room = 102) AND ((startDate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))) OR (stopDate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)))) order BY room";
```

And right JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "room": "100",
      "period": [
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-02-03",
          "checkOut": "2015-02-11"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "room": "101",
      "period": [
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-02-03",
          "checkOut": "2015-02-04"
        },
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-02-22",
          "checkOut": "2015-03-08"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "room": "102",
      "period": [
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-01-27",
          "checkOut": "2015-01-29"
        },
        {
          "checkIn": "2015-02-05",
          "checkOut": "2015-02-10"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "success": true,
    "msg": ""
  }
}
```

Thx!!!

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do. Please add sample of expected output.

Comment: Can you show your sql? I think you should first get all the rooms and for each room get the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code:

```
$previous = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $current = $row['room'];
    if ($current != $previous) {
        $calendarr = new Calendar();
        $calendarr->room = $row['room'];
        $calendarr->period = array();
        $calendar[] = $calendarr;
        $previous = $current;
    }

    $order = new Period();
    $order->checkIn = $row['startDate'];
    $order->checkOut = $row['stopDate'];
    $calendarr->period[] = $order;
}
return $calendar;
```

The problem is that you create new objects when the room is the same.